# @Resource annotation for JNDI datasource injection in tomat 7

Tags: java, jdbc, jndi

I am working with a project with accesses a `JNDI` datasource in tomcat 7. Here is my META-INF/context.xml files:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context>

    <Resource name="jdbc/ambes" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="" 
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ANTTestDb"/>

   </Context>
```

This is my dao class, the dataSource is successfully injected to my class via context lookup service as you see below:

```
  public class CoffeeDataBase {

  private DataSource dataSource;

  public CoffeeDataBase() {

    try {

        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ambes");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   // other methods definition

}
```

but when i replace the lookup service with @Resourse anotaion  like this:

```
  @Resource(lookup="java:comp/env/jdbc/ambes")
  public class CoffeeDataBase {

  private DataSource dataSource;

  public CoffeeDataBase() {
  }

   // other methods definition

}
```

i am getting this NullPointerExeption like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ambestephen.dao.CoffeeDataBase.getCoffeeList(CoffeeDataBase.java:63)
    at com.ambestephen.controller.ShowCoffees.doGet(ShowCoffees.java:16)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have also tried `@Resource(name="jdbc/ambes")` but same exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat does not support @Resource injection. So you can only use context lookup service in you are working in Tomcat. You can also use dependency injection framework spring to inject the dataSource which enables you to use @Resource anotation.

Comment: It did in Tomcat 6. Stopped working in Tomcat 7 for reasons I have never had explained.

Comment: Web containers supporting Servlet 3.0 must implement this.  Your web app needs to declare that it is at that leve.